# when using requests I GET the html but all of the [š, č, ž,..] characters are changed

Tags: python, html, python-requests, get

```
> data = requests.get("https://urnik.fmf.uni-lj.si/letnik/31/")
> print(data.text)
```

This is what it prints out:
[image: result]

nothing I've tried has worked so far...

Comment: I pasted it into my code and it wokrs without problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved
The problem was just the console I was using (git) doesn't show them...

Answer (score 0):

```
data.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(data.text)
```